# How to convert Pandas MultiIndex/PeriodIndex to Dict while keeping values and periods separate

Tags: python, pandas, serialization

How can I complete the conversion of a pandas multi-indexed dataframe into the appropriate dict output. Example, attempt, and intended output below.

Example data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Setup Data/Define Helper func for Dict -> Multi-Index DF

def dict_to_multiDF_format(dictionary: dict) -> Dict:
    return {(outerKey, innerKey): values for outerKey, innerDict in dictionary.items() for innerKey, values in
           innerDict.items()}

d = {
    'x': {'y': np.random.rand(4), 'z': np.random.randn(4)},
    'aa': {'y': np.random.rand(4), 'z': np.random.randn(4)}
    }

# Create DF w/ PeriodIndex
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_to_multiDF_format(d))
df.index = pd.PeriodIndex(start='01-2018', end='04-2018', freq='M')
```

Now that the DF is created, I'd like to be able to get it back out to a multi-level dict format. I modified the following from a different SO answer which brings me almost there:

```
def multiDF_to_dict(df: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    return df.T.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name).to_dict('index')).to_dict()
```

At this point, the resulting dict type mapping would be Dict[str, Dict[str, Dict[pd.Period, float]]]. What I'd like to be able to return is Dict[str, Dict[str, List[float]]] where, in example above, I could call:

```
output = multiDF_to_dict(df)

# the following to be True
isinstance(output['x']['z'], list)
isinstance(output['x']['z'][0], float)

isinstance(output['periods'], list)
isinstance(output['periods'][0], pd.Period)
```

Note that the pd.Period has been moved as an outer dict item as it applies across all values.

Edit: To better explain the output, the output dict above returns:

```
In[163]: output['x']['z']
Out[163]: 
{Period('2018-01', 'M'): 1.0308097883976446,
 Period('2018-02', 'M'): 0.6475015766242127,
 Period('2018-03', 'M'): 0.6703669301328639,
 Period('2018-04', 'M'): -0.9079304895787961}
```

I'd like the same call to return:

```
[1.0308097883976446, 0.6475015766242127, 0.6703669301328639,-0.9079304895787961]
```

and

```
In[164]: output['periods'] # from PeriodIndex
Out[164]: ['2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04']
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make it very clear what the output should look like. How about an example output?